# Equivalent for sonar.visualstudio.skippedProjectPattern in MSBuild Runner?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

This is a second question based on the same situation described in [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817430/migrating-from-sonar-runner-to-msbuild-runner-where-did-the-sonar-project-prope).

We have a number of projects that get built several times, as they are included in several different solutions.  Yet we only want them to be analyzed once, each as part of a specific solution.  How do we exclude these project from analysis when analyzing the other solutions?  I have tried passing `/d:sonar.visualstudio.skippedProjectPattern=...` on the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner command line but it seems to  have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `sonar.visualstudio.skippedProjectPattern` in the MSBuild SonarQube Runner 1.0. I've created a ticket to the backlog http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-123 to consider adding this feature in a future release.

Comment: Thank you for creating SONARMSBRU-123 and SONARMSBRU-124.  Unfortunately the lack of these features means we cannot upgrade from the sonar-runner to the MSBuild runner.  This makes the fact that SonarSource no longer supports the sonar-runner for .net projects a bit problematic.

Comment: Don't worry too much - we'll address the shortcoming of the MSBuild SonarQube Runner that we failed to foresee quickly in the upcoming versions